# How to list duplicate values in a dictionary that represents flights?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that had another dictionary and some lists inside that.

```
flightsD={"Delta":{1102:[["IND",1850],["MDW",1955]],
               1096:[["PHX",900],["MDW",1255]],
               1445:[["ATL",1135],["LAX",1810]],
               1776:[["PHL",1350],["RAP",1610]],
               1226:[["PHX",950],["MDW",1345]],
               1885:[["ATL",1305],["LAX",2000]],
               1009:[["MDW",1850],["IND",1955]],
               9001:[["MDW",2145],["IND",2255]]},
      "Southwestern":{1111:[["SAT",430],["MDW",825]],
                      2121:[["MDW",430],["SAT",825]],
                      4335:[["PHX",450],["MDW",745]],
                      1102:[["MDW",1100],["PHX",1450]]},
      "American":{7765:[["IND",1850],["CHA",2105]],
               2133:[["BNA",900],["IND",1115]],
               3321:[["HOU",1335],["ATL",1615]],
               2100:[["BNA",900],["IND",1115]],
               4311:[["HOU",905],["ATL",1255]],
               5577:[["ATL",1100],["HOU",1350]],
               1102:[["BNA",1100],["HOU",1450]]}  }
```

As you can see, Delta, Southwestern and American all have a flights 1102. I would like to list all duplicate flights as a list inside a dictionary.
Expected output:

```
{1102: ['American', 'Southwestern', 'Delta']}
```

I have tried to access these values by iterating through the dictionary like so:

```
for airline in flightsD:
    for flights in flightsD[airline]:
```

I am thinking about making a list to store all of these values but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the dict items, use `dict.setdefault` to initialize the output dict with a list to append airlines to, and use a dict comprehension to output items with sublists with more than 1 item:

```
d = {}
for airline, flights in flightsD.items():
    for flight in flights:
        d.setdefault(flight, []).append(airline)
print({k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1})
```

This outputs:

```
{1102: ['Delta', 'Southwestern', 'American']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

airlines, schedules = flightsD.keys(), flightsD.values()

flight_nums = [s.keys() for s in schedules]

duplicates = defaultdict(list)
for i, item1 in enumerate(flight_nums):
    for j, item2 in enumerate(flight_nums):       
        for k in item1:
            if i != j and k in item2 and airlines[i] not in duplicates[k]:
                duplicates[k].append(airlines[i])


print(duplicates)

>>> {1102: ['American', 'Southwestern', 'Delta']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dictionary with *just* those values, you can use the code below (based on the code above):

```
list = []
for flights in flightsD.values():
    list.extend(flights.keys())

d = {}
for airline, flights in flightsD.items():
    for flight in flights:
        if list.count(flight) > 1:
            d.setdefault(flight, []).append(airline)
```